# How to make responsive screen for web in expo react native

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, react-native-web, expo-web

Now. I am Using react-native-responsive-screen. its working fine for mobiles. But Now I want to run website also from same code base. but in website width is so much stretched .
means width = wp('90%'). its looking so much wide on website on desktop. And if I make it wp('50%). then if I make it like mobile size in browser then its becoming to short. so please suggest me on How to make responsive screens for website in react native exppo.